# Problem with pattern matching in Drools 7.57.0.Final

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I'm trying to run [this GitHub project](https://github.com/aasaru/drools-training) using Drools *7.57.0.Final* instead of *7.39.0.Final* which was used in original project. And I found some issues. The issue that most triggers me is the one in the Section 6, Step 5. The problem lies in the Drools file *VisaApplicationValidationWithAgendaAndSalience.drl*. Here is the content with the "debug" statement that I have added:

```
package io.github.aasaru.drools.section06.step5

import io.github.aasaru.drools.domain.Passport;
import io.github.aasaru.drools.domain.Validation;
import io.github.aasaru.drools.domain.VisaApplication;

import java.time.LocalDate;

rule "Invalidate visa application with invalid passport"
  dialect "mvel"
  agenda-group "validate-application"
  salience 20
  when
    $passport: Passport( validation == Validation.FAILED )
    $visaApplication: VisaApplication( passportNumber == $passport.passportNumber,
                                       validation != Validation.FAILED )
  then
    System.out.println( "Set " + $visaApplication + " invalid as " + $passport + " hasn't passed validation");
    modify($visaApplication) {
      setValidation( Validation.FAILED )
    }
end

rule "Set application without validation info as passed"
  dialect "mvel"
  agenda-group "validate-application"
  salience 10
  when
    $visaApplication: VisaApplication( validation == Validation.UNKNOWN )
  then
  System.out.println("debug >>>>>>>>>>>>>  " + $visaApplication.validation);
    System.out.println( $visaApplication + " is without validation info, consider OK for now" );
    modify($visaApplication) {
      setValidation( Validation.PASSED )
    }
end

rule "Invalidate visa application where passport expires earlier than 6 months after visit end date"
  dialect "mvel"
  agenda-group "validate-application"
  salience 20
  when
    $passport: Passport( validation != Validation.FAILED )
    $visaApplication: VisaApplication( passportNumber == $passport.passportNumber,
                                       $passport.expiresOn.isBefore(visitEndDate.plusMonths(6)),
                                       validation != Validation.FAILED )
  then
    System.out.println( "Set " + $visaApplication + " invalid as " + $passport + " not valid 6 months after visit");
    modify($visaApplication) {
      setValidation( Validation.FAILED )
    }
end
```

and here is the part of the console output that regards to the previous rules:

```
Set VisaApplication(#1, pass:CA-SARAH-1) invalid as Passport[no:CA-SARAH-1, name:Sarah Murphy] hasn't passed validation
Set VisaApplication(#4, pass:AU-JAMES-4) invalid as Passport[no:AU-JAMES-4, name:James Brown] not valid 6 months after visit
debug >>>>>>>>>>>>>  FAILED
VisaApplication(#1, pass:CA-SARAH-1) is without validation info, consider OK for now
Set VisaApplication(#1, pass:CA-SARAH-1) invalid as Passport[no:CA-SARAH-1, name:Sarah Murphy] hasn't passed validation
debug >>>>>>>>>>>>>  UNKNOWN
VisaApplication(#2, pass:CA-SIMON-2) is without validation info, consider OK for now
debug >>>>>>>>>>>>>  UNKNOWN
VisaApplication(#3, pass:AU-EMILY-3) is without validation info, consider OK for now
```

As is obvious, the middle rule, the one with the `salience 10`, has been fired not only for the pattern `validation == Validation.UNKNOWN` but also for the pattern `validation == Validation.FAILED`! That is wrong and it happens in Drools *7.57.0.Final* and doesn't happen in Drools *7.39.0.Final* used by the original project. Is it a Drools bug or what? I'm pretty new to Drools so this really confuses me.

Second, why do I get the console output `Set VisaApplication(#1, pass:CA-SARAH-1) ...` twice? It seems to be a consequence of the reevaluation of the 1st rule, but this shouldn't have happened as this is the stateful and not the stateless session.

> If you want to reproduce the console log, download the project, change Drools version to the latest one  *7.57.0.Final*, run the app `io.github.aasaru.drools.section06.VisaIssue`, and when asked,
> enter `5` for the step and `no` when asked whether all passports should be considered as expired.

Comment: Interesting catch. You're correct in your understanding. The passport is invalid, so the first rule calls `modify(...)` to set the application state to invalid. The second rule should therefore _not_ fire, because `modify` has updated working memory such that the rule no longer matches (rule should only trigger when application state is unknown).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulation, you found drools bug [DROOLS-6542](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-6542) - **fixed in 7.60.0.Final**
There is a workaround - remove mvel dialect for the `rule "Invalidate visa application with invalid passport"`.

BTW, I'd like to propose you drools testing [library](https://github.com/droolsassert/droolsassert/wiki) which may save you great amount of time to mind complicated rules and simplify writing test scenarios. Here is how test may look like.

```
@DroolsSession(
        resources = "classpath*:**/section06/step5/*",
        showStateTransitionPopup = true)
public class Section6Step5Test {
    
    @RegisterExtension
    public DroolsAssert drools = new DroolsAssert();
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        
        ApplicationRepository.getPassports().forEach(drools::insert);
        ApplicationRepository.getVisaApplications().forEach(drools::insert);
        
        drools.getSession().getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("issue-visa").setFocus();
        drools.getSession().getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("validate-application").setFocus();
        drools.getSession().getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("validate-passport").setFocus();
        
        drools.fireAllRules();
        
        assertEquals(1, drools.getObjects(Visa.class).size());
    }
}
```

Here is visualization popup of the test on 7.39.0.Final (or 7.57.0.Final without mvel dialect).

[image]

and the same on 7.57.0.Final (with mvel dialect)

[image]

Comment: How'd you generate the visualization?

Comment: Sweet. I've never tried that before. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, for reporting the bug and suggesting the testing library. Since I'm newbie to the Drools, I was a bit hesitant to report a bug so I decided to ask a question at the stackoverflow. Now, I'm even more confused with your workaround. Without `mvel`, the dialect defaults to Java and we still have the `mvel` syntax used in the `when` part of the rule. How should I understand that? And finally, how did you came up with workaround? What was the logic behind it?

Comment: `when` block is not `mvel` it is proprietary drools syntax. Syntax switch relates only to `then` block (btw, you can write it once at the beginning of the file). The problem is in `update` statement, it works for java and don't for mvel. When it works new state of the `VisaApplication` causes `when` block of other rules no longer match and rule is removed from the agenda queue (execution queue). When it doesn't, other rules relay on stale object state and get's executed.

Comment: First I reproduced different behavior on the versions you've provided with a test. Then I checked versions one-by-one to get the version issue started to be reproduced. Then I checked git commits to understand what could be possible commit that introduced a bug. Usually you can find exact code change with the bug inside, but it was a bit more complicated. I found commits related to the jira, user was arguing `update` get applied 'too wide' and the fix for this. Now we are experience an issue when `update` is not getting applied (exactly the opposite). So my best guess it was related.

Comment: I saw commits saying logic change exactly to mvel update, not to the update in general, so I made a try with java dialect on my test and it worked as expected, so I got more details for the jira and the workaround. After that I was removing properties and other stuff to make example as simple as possible but reproduce the problem and compiled an example for the jira. BTW, I was trying to compile an example from the scratch with my own models and I was not able to reproduce the issue with mvel update. This means that your example is somehow unique. Like it was said before 'interesting catch' ;)

Comment: First of all, thanks for clarifying what block `mvel` relates to and that arised a new question for me. It seems that `mvel` is not consistent with its syntax. E.g, if we enable `mvel` dialect, the following construct in a `then` block works: `modify($visaApplication) { setValidation( Validation.FAILED ) }` but I expected that `mvel` syntax would have been something like this: `modify($visaApplication) { validation = Validation.FAILED }`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work but this one does: `$visaApplication.validation = Validation.FAILED` (`modify` block is not needed here!). Of course, that doesn't solve the problem of this topic, but I just wanted to point that out at this place.

Comment: Next, a few words about conclusion related to `mvel` update. Namely, it seems that update works, but pattern matching at the rule *"Set application without validation info as passed"* does not. Take a look again at the console log which prints out the *debug* statement. We have a case where `UNKNOWN` matches `FAILED`. That's wrong! So it seems that update in the 1st rule did its work but matcher in the 2nd one, did not. I can also guess that the `mvel` update has been somehow delayed to occur after the pattern matching in the second rule happens.